# Rendering rails output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to set up my simple form outputs in my Rails 4 app.

I have a project model, a scope model and a participant model.

Participant belongs to scope. Scope belongs to Project.

The participant model has two attributes - one for 'location_specific', which is a boolean and one for 'location' which is a string.

If location_specific is true, then I want to output the location that is required.

In my participants show partial, I have:

```
<div class="datasubtextq">Location:
        <span class="datasubtext">
          <% if @project.scope.participant.location_specific == true %>
            <%=  @project.scope.participant.location %>
          <% else %>
            <%= render :text => "Remote participation" %>
          <% end %>
        </span>
  </div>
```

In my form, I have:

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <%= f.label 'Can participants participate remotely?', :class => 'question-project' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <%= par.collection_radio_buttons :location_specific, [[true, ' Yes'], [false, ' No']], :first, :last, {:item_wrapper_class => 'fixradio'}, {:class => "response-project"} %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="requiredlocation">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
            <%= f.label 'Select participation location', :class => 'question-project' %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="response-project">
            <%= par.select :location,
                           options_for_select(["New York", "Boston", "Florida"]),
                           label: 'Where will participants take part in this project?',
                           prompt: "Choose one",
                           class: 'response-project' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My problem is that each time I try this, I get the 'remote participation alternative. The City option is not displaying as it should. Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Thank you

Comment: print the value of @project.scope.participant

Comment: try to do like this " <% if @project.scope.participant.location_specific %><% else %><% end %>"

Comment: Hi Gaurav, i can't see how that's different to what I've done.

Comment: Hi 123 - how do i do that?

Comment: You can check the value in your rails console or you can output it <%= @project.scope.participant.location_specific %>.  It would appear that this value is always false if you're getting the 'Remote Participation' text.

Comment: `<%= @project.scope.participant %>`  add this line to participants/_show.html.erb and paste that value here

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks - it comes up as false (even when I select true). Something must be wrong in saving to the database.

Comment: Thanks user123, I get a string of letters and numbers when I paste that line.